# css-stylesheet for google map infoWindows

Tags: css, google-maps, infowindow

In my web application I am showing infoWindows in a google map.

The default design is very primitive and I would like to have something nicer.

Is there a css-stylesheet available that I can include, which provides nice styles for the infoWindows?

I haven't found anything useful so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write Css for Info Window

```
<style type="text/css">
    .info-win {
        padding: 5px;
        width: 350px;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 1.8;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Create a string Which contain HTML elements and then set it as a content of info window.

```
    var htmlcontent = '<div class="info-win"><span><p style="background:#CCDF31;padding:3px 5px;color:#000;">Info Win Design</p></span></div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: htmlcontent
        });
```